# Primeng file uploader: file selection window shows twice on choose file button click

Tags: angular, primeng

I have updated primeng from 9 to 10.0.3. After the update, the file selection window shows twice on choose file button click. After the first selection, the window gets closed and popouts again. And if I select a file again, the file gets selected.

But drag and drop works as normal. I'm totally confused. Am I missing something?

I tried primeng file upload in a standalone application, it works fine. I don't know what change during the update caused this issue.

```
<div class="col-md-4" >
  <div class="form-group drop-files noLabel">
    <p-fileUpload #fileuploadcontrol class="ie-file-upload" (onSelect)="SelectFiles($event)" accept=".csv,.xlsx,.xls" maxFileSize="100000000">
    </p-fileUpload>
  </div>
</div>
```

This debugger is triggered only after the second selection

```
SelectFiles(event) {
    debugger
    for (let file of event.files) {

      this.attachedFiles.push(file);
      this.attachFileCounter = this.attachFileCounter + 1;
      //if (this.attachedFiles.length < 1) {
      let attachmentDetails: AttachmentDetails = {
        attachmentPath: file.name,
        attachmentId: 0,
        templateID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        isActive: 1
      }
      this.attachmentList.push(attachmentDetails);
      //}
    }
  }
```

The code worked fine before the update. Any help is much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: try once deleting `node_modules` folder of your application, then reinstall again with `npm i` check again if it works for you or not ?

Comment: Tried it already. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. A custom button was added and the default choose button was hidden. When I click the button pointer event was getting triggered for both the buttons.
As a solution, I just disabled the pointer-events for the default button

```
.p-button.p-fileupload-choose input[type=file]{
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```